Flutter Web - Localhost request to maps.googleapis.com
I am working on a flutter project and have run into an issue where I am unable to make web request to the google maps directions API. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions
I have already tried setting the restrictions to web and adding localhost.  When that didnt work, I set it to be none to see if that made a difference, but no luck.  Unfortunately the response I get back using DIO isn't very helpful.  Here is the error message and code sample below.
"The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on the network layer. This indicates an error which most likely cannot be solved by the library."
Future<List<LatLng>> fetchRouteCoordinates(LatLng start, LatLng end) async {
    try {
      const String baseUrl =
          'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json';
      const String apiKey =
          '<API Key>'; // Replace with your Google Maps API key

      // final url = Uri.parse(
      //     '$baseUrl?origin=${start.latitude},${start.longitude}&destination=${end.latitude},${end.longitude}&key=$apiKey');

      final response = await Dio(BaseOptions()).get(
          '$baseUrl?origin=${start.latitude},${start.longitude}&destination=${end.latitude},${end.longitude}&key=$apiKey');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.data);
        final polyline = data['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'];
        return decodePolyline(polyline);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load directions');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log.e(e);
      return [];
    }
  }

EDIT:  I have tested this on both Android and in Postman and it works.  Any other ideas.
EDIT 2: I was able to get around this by making an API Controller and making the request there and then returning that data.

This seems like a CORS issue. In this case, you should use a backend as a proxy to execute the network requests.

This request works on Android just not on Flutter Web.

Then seems like a CORS issue, it is a browser-enforced restriction

It appears you are right.  I ended up making the call in my api and it works fine.

Feel free to accept the answer :)

Is it a Cors Policy issue maybe?
You can try using this line to test:
const String proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const String baseUrl = proxyUrl + "BASE_URL.com";


I tried this but no luck.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
